# Can't add JDBC driver to Library scope

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, glassfish

I am currently trying to contact a MySQL server.
My goal is to have a servlet that will show some table data when run.
My servelt is running on **glassfish 3.1**.

Here is the simple **doGet** method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
    out.print("<h1>select * from userName:<h1>");

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/people", "root", "r00tpw");
        System.out.println("Connected");

        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("select * from userName");
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()) {
            out.print(result.getString(0));
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have got the correct JDBC driver. The problem I have is with my source code finding it. I have tried right clicking **JRE System Library->Build Path->Configure Build Path** and adding an external JAR. Rather than adding the JAR to **Referenced Libraries** it seems to be added outside of any library scope. This means that `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` is always throwing a ClassNotFoundException.

I have also tried adding the JAR to my **Run Configurations->Glassfish 3.1 at [pcname]->Classpath->User Entries** with no luck.

I have also tried using MS SQL Server and their JDBC driver. The same thing happens.

I have attached an image of my project structure to help.

[image: What my project explorer looks like after including in claspath]

Comment: Do you have the jar file marked for export in the Build Path?

Comment: @KevinBowersox When expanding the JAR in the classpath view I see the following: Source attachment(none) Javadoc location (none) Native Library Location (None) Access Rules (No restrictions)

Comment: There must be some scope, as when I remove the JAR from the project, the Type `PreparedStatement` can't be resolved.

Comment: The Build Path is not used for assembling the WAR file.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4631238/53897

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all after you install jdbc driver you need to configure it in glassfish. Create a JDBC resource and JDBC connection pool.

PS Did you add the jdbc JAR to glassfish server folder?

For glassfish too see your connector it must reside in \Glassfish3\domains\domain1\lib\databases

Answer (score 1):

Put the mysql-connector-java-5.1.26 to your  **WebContent--->WEB-INF-->lib**.inside lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not added mysql driver to a server folder. Therefore, did you check your `glassfish-resources.xml` or JDBC connection in Glassfish admin console?